# Resonance Audio, cannot found occlusion setting and HRTF details

Tags: resonance-audio

I just installed Unreal 4.19 Preview 2 and saw Resonance Audio plugin and installed it. 
However, there is no occlusion setting and Spatilize details. Anybody help me T.T

Answer (score 2):

The way audio plugin settings are added has changed a little bit in UE 4.19. In your Audio Component's *Details* panel, make sure that the *Override Attenuation* box is ON and then scroll down until you see *[Attenuation Plugin Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI4QK.jpg)*:

Now, you should be able to add the *Resonance Audio Spatialization Source Settings* to control the spatialization parameters of your source(s).

If you cannot create the settings, make sure that the Resonance Audio Spatialization plugin is enabled on your platform (for example, on Windows, go to to Project Settings->Platforms->Windows->Audio and make sure you have the [following settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBh2l.png)).

Regarding the Occlusion Plugin, you will need v1.1.1 of the Resonance Audio plugin (which currently works with UE 4.18.2) or v1.2.0 (coming soon) which will work with UE 4.19. Please see https://developers.google.com/resonance-audio/develop/unreal/getting-started for more details on how to get the latest version of the Resonance Audio plugin for Unreal.